# Like case sensitive in room persistence library

Tags: android, android-room

How to apply case sensitive with LIKE query when use room persistence library android??

using below query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE category_name LIKE '%' || :categoryName|| '%'")
List<Category> getAllCategory(@Nullable String categoryName);
```

Use `PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = on` not working

Comment: see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html - the section `The LIKE, GLOB, REGEXP, and MATCH operators`

Comment: @pskink i know how to use with sql query but dont know to apply this with room in android

Comment: so what does your `@Query("sqlite select staement")` looks like? what do you have problems with?

Comment: right wait let me update my answer

Comment: tried `GLOB` instead of `LIKE`?

Comment: also how are you using `PRAGMA` statement? inside `RoomDatabase.Callback#onOpen`?

Comment: GLOB is not working get zero row

Comment: yes GLOB is working - read the docs i posted in my first comment, and how are you using `PRAGMA` statement? whats your code which uses `PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = on`?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_glob_clause.htm - why dont you try `googling` before asking the same question again and again? *"Unlike LIKE operator, GLOB is case sensitive and it follows syntax of UNIX for specifying THE following wildcards.

The asterisk sign (*)
The question mark (?)
The asterisk sign (*) represents zero or multiple numbers or characters. The question mark (?) represents a single number or character."*

Comment: thank i remember this

Comment: yup, please post your answer

Comment: GLOB '*' || :categoryName|| '*' working for me

Comment: so post a self answer then

Comment: I did it in this way: `WHERE UPPER(category_name)=:input_category_name` and passed input by converting to upper case like: `input_category_name.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault())`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Help of pskink found answer:

Use GLOB instead of LIKE, Successful Query as below

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE category_name GLOB '*' || :categoryName|| '*'")
List<Category> getAllCategory(@Nullable String categoryName);
```

Comment: I'm doing this to avoid inserting the same word twice but it is not working, I search for Hello it does ok, but if I search for hello instead of returning the results for hello it just insert a new row ...

Comment: are you using GLOB, then read this link i hope its helpful for you https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like